# Aliasing issues (public reference to a private object inside a class)

Tags: java

I'm reading Thinking in Java. The chapter about access (private, public etc.). This is a quotation from the book:

> ...just because a reference to an object is private inside a class
>   doesn't mean that some other object can't have a public reference to
>   the same object.

Then we are redirected to the online supplements for the book to learn about aliasing issues.

On the official site there is a solution guide for the book. But it is expensive for me.

Could you clarify what is meant by that aliasing issues so that I could google more examples.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example

```
public class Foo {}
public class PrivateExample {
    private Foo foo;
    public PrivateExample (Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
public class PublicExample {
    public Foo foo;
}
...
// in some method
Foo foo = new Foo();
PrivateExample privateExample = new PrivateExample(foo);
PublicExample publicExample = new PublicExample();
publicExample.foo = foo;
```

Now both the `PrivateExample` instance and the `PublicExample` instance have a reference to the same `Foo` object. Note that even the method has a reference to the object. So even though you can't access it through the `PrivateExample` instance, you have access to it through the others. It is not necessarily safe.

Comment: I was writing the exact same example. +1.

Comment: Is this called aliasing? I would say this is violation of incapsulation principle.

Comment: @user3475946 There's probably some not so healthy encapsulation going on, but aliasing simply refers to having many variables referencing the same object.